# IntelliJ IDEA - add library from Eclipse

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-actionbar

Created a new Android project. 
Added the library (https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) for instructions http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/sharing-android-source-code-and-resources-using-library-projects.html. 
In the code of the class Actionbar works.

BUT the problem - layout does not find com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add it as a separate module instead of the library and in the `Android Facet` settings of this module enable "**Is Library Project**" option. Then add this module as a dependency to your main application.